# Skipping properties of nested collections when mapping with model mapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a source class to map as UserDao. I want to map this source class to UserViewModel destination class, there I need to skip the permissions property of RoleViewModel collection property in UserViewModel destination class. Is there any built in method possible. I tried with property map as well as converters and couldn't find a way. Helps would be appreciated.

**UserViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel {
    private int id;
    private List<RoleViewModel> roles;
}
```

**RoleViewModel**

```
public class RoleViewModel {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<PermissionViewModel> permissions;
}
```

These are the corresponding source class objects.
**UserDao**

```
public class UserDao {
    private int id;
    private Set<RoleDao> roles;
}
```

**RoleDao**

```
public class RoleDao {
    private int id;
    private String roleName;
    private Set<PermissionDao> permissions;
}
```